# Having "Assembly is incorrectly configured: null" when trying to use the maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am using maven-assembly-plugin verions 3.2.0, initially I thought adding "appendAssemblyId" would solve it but it does not.

```
 <configuration>
    <descriptors>
       <descriptor>src/main/resources/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Why are you using the assembly plugin? Spring Boot already generates a jar that contains everything.

Comment: Well im working on this big project , and for the deployment of this specific app will require external dependencies.

Comment: If it needs external dependencies those should be added to pom file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried adding id tag inside assembly and surprisingly it worked

```
<id>assembly-id</id>
```

Comment: Same for me. Seems this is a required field.

Comment: In my case I've added the <id> tag  in assembly.xml file as you said and i worked too

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the id tag is already set but same error still happened. Finally, I found out it was working when the version of the `maven-dependency-plugin` was the old one, which mine is `2.2-beta-5`, and it failed when a version was set to `3.6.0`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was having a conflict between two versions of maven assembly plugin. After resolving the conflict, issue got fixed.